# Is it proper to use if/else to avoid division by zero in the compute() define section?

Tags: openmdao

I'm new to the OpenMDAO framework and trying to build a explicit self-defined model and use SimpleGADriver to perform a multi-objective MIP optimization. While using`class MyModel(ExplicitComponent):`to define my model, within the `def compute()`section, I have a function that calculate an output like `output_a = output_b / output_c`, where the output_c variable happen to be zero in some cases. I'm currently using

```
def compute()
  if output_c != 0:
    output_a = output_b / output_c
  else:
    output_a = output_b / 1e-10
```

To be specific, the physical meaning of the variable output_c is the diameter of a spring(D) subtracted by the diameter of the spring coil(d). Besides, these two inputs (D and d) are discrete inputs, so while the GA driver randomly generating designs, it is unavoidable to have D == d, which will lead to output_c equals zero.

I feellike this might not be the best practice to dealing with division by zero problems in the OpenMDAO although the optimization runs fine. Could anyone let me know if there are other recommended ways of dealing with division by zero in OpenMDAO?

I checked OpenMDAO webpage for guides and examples but nothing found, I am currently having no better solutions…

Comment: I urge you to question the meaning of situations where `output_c` could be zero.

Comment: Thank you Yves for you suggestion, I have updated those info in my question

Comment: Maybe you should re-parameterize your inputs so that you have dv1 = d (coil diam) and dv2 = D - d (spring thickness) , and then encode the thickness with a minimum value that is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully admit to having used a similar technique myself to deal with division by zero.

I do something like this:

```
output_a = output_b / (output_c + 1e-20)
```

Which is basically similar to your approach, but has very slightly better numerical properties because my version is technically C1 continuous and yours is C1 discontinuous at 0. However, in practice both approaches have numerical problems because you're still dividing by a tiny number and you have poor control over the behavior there.

Yves Daoust's comment is on point though, and hints at what I would typically recommend in these situations. You can't have a zero spring diameter, but as you said your current parameterization of the space makes it so that a zero is valid. In fact, it seems likely you could even have negative values.

So I would typically suggest that you reparameterize your problem to have use the spring coil diameter and the delta between that and the diameter. Then for any positive value of that delta, you are ensured a valid physical spring. This is a fundamentally more well posed design space that you can easily apply variable bounds to ensure you always remain physically valid (i.e. delta_diam > 0.001)

If you were using gradient based methods, this kind of reparameterization would be fully critical to getting any kind of results at all. With a GA, its a double edged sword. Technically you can get away with having this kind of infeasible hole in your design space. However, you need to do two things:

1. make your model robust to that failure. So your if statement (or my modified version) is a good way to avoid the divide by zero problem. But you may need to make changes in other places downstream too.
2. Make sure you properly alert the optimizer of the problem. In your case, you might want to add some kind of component that checks the values and heavily penalizes the objective function when it detects this kind of numerical instability. That helps the GA to stay out of those areas, though your results now become highly dependent on the type of penalty function you use and how strong you make it.

I will stress that I don't like this approach. Re-parameterizing is a much better choice ... so I also

> "urge you to question the meaning of situations where output_c could
> be zero!" -- Yves Daoust

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer Justin,  it explains a lot. I will definetly start trying to refining my project. However, another thing that confuses me right now is that whether the fuction I write in the compute section are solved as a equation system or they just compose a calculation script for each output. To be more specific, for example, dose the sequence of these equations(or maybe functions) matters? Thanks again for your reply

Comment: I can't quite follow your question, and it sounds like you're asking about something different now. I suggest you post a separate question with some kind of example script to clarify what you're asking